# WAS 9 how override default provided MyFaces2.2 on Websphere Application Server V9

Tags: java, web, jakarta-ee, server, websphere

we are migrating from WAS 8 to WAS 9 and WAS9 is providing MyFaces 2.2 but we would like to override with MyFaces following jars

- myfaces-extcdi-core-api-1.0.5.jar
- myfaces-extcdi-core-impl-1.0.5.jar
- myfaces-extcdi-jsf20-module-api-1.0.5.jar
- myfaces-extcdi-jsf20-module-impl-1.0.5.jar
- myfaces-extcdi-message-module-api-1.0.5.jar
- myfaces-extcdi-message-module-impl-1.0.5.jar

basically we don't need WAS provided MyFaces , when I can uninstall myfaces on WAS 9 server, I see the MyFaces jars "Plugins" folder.

- removing jars from plugins folder is not working

any suggestions please

Comment: Please research a bit by yourself... MyFaces ExtCDI is not the JSF impl MyFacesCore and you can't overwrite apples with bananas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MyFaces JSF implementation provided with WAS 9 cannot be uninstalled.  You should not remove any jars from `plugins`.  In WAS versions 8.0 and 8.5.5 an application option was provided to select between SunRI and MyFaces - however in WAS 9 only MyFaces 2.2 is provided, so there is no such configuration option.

IBM has a documentation page for [configuring JSF](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tweb_jsf22.html).  Once you've determined the correct MyFaces libraries to use, you'll want to bundle those libraries (as well as the correct dependencies) into an isolated shared library.